# How to offer the user a large number of list to run

Tags: buttons, web-app

we are currently developing a big business web application. On some pages, we must allow the user to run many different lists. By list, I mean PDF file (reporting).

In the old version of our application, we just put a lot of buttons on the screen, with the title of the list on it. But it's very ugly !

[image: Old application]

Our idea is to add some pictograms to each button for characterizing each list (portrait/landscape, ...) but I don't think it's enough.

Any ideas, directions, reading, ... ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it a categorized link. Make the category as parent level link, on-click of that links you can open the child inks. In this format you can manage huge number of links.

Comment: Thank you. Ok for grouping but the idea would be to have more than just a button or a link.

Answer (score 1):

How about your use blurbs ? Use relevant pictures with your heading.

[image]

Else all links will also do, provided you properly categorize them like for instance, see below

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Good point for blurbs. But I search something more than just button or link...